# How to Store the String Value in Char array in java..?

Tags: java, string, swing

I have to Store the String value in fixed char array, i tried but after storing the value char array size changed depends upon the String Value... Can Any one tell me how to fix that issue..

```
char[] uniqueID = new char[10];
String lUniqueID = mUniqueIdTxtFld.getText();  
uniqueID = lUniqueID.toCharArray();
```

O/P:

```
lUniqueID=12D;     
 it show in uniqueID[1,2,D]...
```

But i need `[1,2,D,,,,,,,,]`

(ie) fixed Char array, it should not change.. Any one suggestion me what is wrong on that.

Comment: char is a primitive type. A char array is filled with 0 by default. So, what  you'll get is `'1','2','D',0,0,0,0,0,0,0`. Why would you want that? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: thx for reply.. i want to store the string value with fixed size

Comment: That I understand. But why? What's the point?

Comment: that string value write in the file with fixed size.

Comment: So, why not write the string, and then use a loop to write the N missing blank characters?

Comment: ok i will try for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current problem is that when doing `uniqueID = lUniqueID.toCharArray();` you are assigning a new char array to `uniqueID` and not the content of it into the previous array defined.

What you want to achieve can be done using [`Arrays.copyOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28char%5B%5D,%20int%29).

```
char[] uniqueID = Arrays.copyOf(lUniqueID.toCharArray(), 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this method

[System.arraycopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29)

and copy the chars from `uniqueID = lUniqueID.toCharArray();`
to some 10 chars long array `arr` which you created up-front.

Comment: A bit more cumbersome than the Arrays.copyOf hint by ZouZou, which also meets the "0s as padding" requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
public static void main(String arguments[]) {
    char[] padding = new char[10];
    char[] uniqueID = mUniqueIdTxtFld.getText().toCharArray();
    System.arraycopy(uniqueID, 0, padding, 0, Math.min(uniqueID.length, padding.length));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(padding));
}
```

Comment: This won't give 0s as padding in the target array, but ' 's instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the snippet:

```
char[] uniqueID = new char[10];
String lUniqueID = mUniqueIdTxtFld.getText();
char[] compactUniqueID = lUniqueID.toCharArray();
System.arraycopy(compactUniqueID, 0, uniqueID, 0, compactUniqueID.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the yourString.getChars(params) method?

```
    lUniqueId.getChars(0,uniqueID.length,uniqueID, 0);
```